# Why does PIP installation of haystack RAG pipeline lead to metadata generation failure?

Tags: python, pip, haystack

I have been trying to install the RAG pipeline from deepset haystack to create my own  Generative Question Answering pipeline, but everytime I try and install the package, I run into a subprocess error and metadata generation failure

I tried running earlier versions of the Pipline to see if that would fix the issue and check that the libearies I had was up to date along with the pip-tools, ez-setup and wheel
The same result occured.

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
colorama   0.4.6
ez-setup   0.9
iniconfig  2.0.0
packaging  23.2
pip        23.3
pluggy     1.3.0
pytest     7.4.2
setuptools 68.2.2
wheel      0.41.2
```

The Error output:

```
python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\MFV\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j47mkxn9\sentencepiece_61f7ea3936974d68b5d26e271916e631\setup.py", line 126, in <module>
          subprocess.check_call([
        File "C:\Users\MFV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 408, in check_call
          retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\MFV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\MFV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Users\MFV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

this is my first question asked on stack, so I apologize if i've made some beginner errors, tried to follow the guideline as much as I coud.

Comment: Which command do you use to install haystack?

This guide (https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/docs/installation) may help you...

Comment: I use the  install farm-haystack[inference] command, but I have tried different versions of both the basic and custom installation

Comment: Don't try to use a python version (3.12) that came out so recently. Use python 3.11, as there are pre-built whl files available for `sentencepiece` for that version

Comment: Is it a known issue with Python 3.12? Thank you I will try an earlier version and see if that fixes the issues

Comment: Ah... good catch!
Currently, Haystack guarantees support up to Python 3.10. 3.11 may work but is not tested.